# How to fix Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\wamp64\www\newdatabase\datalist.php on line 983

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making up a school project the only error now is this

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable in C:\wamp64\www\newdatabase\datalist.php on line
>   983

```
if(($PrintTV || $Print_x) 
  && count($_REQUEST['record_selector']) 
  && !in_array($row[$FieldCountTV], $_REQUEST['record_selector'])) {
  continue;
}
```

Comment: Not enough information here to help with your question. Please include a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 7.3 you should use the function [is_countable()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-countable.php):

```
if(($PrintTV || $Print_x) 
  && is_countable($_REQUEST['record_selector']) 
  && count($_REQUEST['record_selector']) 
  && !in_array($row[$FieldCountTV], $_REQUEST['record_selector'])) {
  continue;
}
```

In older versions add this:

```
if (!function_exists('is_countable')) {
    function is_countable($var) {
        return (is_array($var) || $var instanceof Countable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has these things called [interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.interfaces.php). Interfaces usually ensure that an object has some functionality by forcing it to have certain methods.

PHP has some special interfaces that do specific things in the language. A great example is [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) which allows you to use the [] operator on your object.

Your code is throwing an error because you're trying to send it to count without implementing the proper interface. The one you need is [Countable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php). Implement this interface in your object properly, and you should be good.

**Edit:** Also, looking at your code again, it could be that you're not sending an array to count(). Ensure `$_REQUEST['record_selector']` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are receiving an array into the count method